# UIViewController's frame on start with UIStatusBar frame at 40 pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, uistatusbar

I don't know if the question title is clear enough but there's a simpler explanation, when I first launch my app and the status bar frame is "modified" at 40 pixels by a call, map updates and any other case like that, and it seems like that state remains through the whole app lifecycle, because when the status bar goes back to 20 pixels, a gap remains on the top ... What am I doing wrong? I'm not using autolayout by the way, would that solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: There's something even more weird, when I first activate in-call status, the frame of the view is right, but then when I deactivate this, the frame gets modified lacking 20 pixels from the in-call status bar. Here are some logs:

```
//View Did Load
2014-05-26 14:16:26.163 X[50414:60b] <UINavigationController: 0x23e87be0>
2014-05-26 14:16:26.164 X[50414:60b] {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
//In-Call Status Bar Activated
2014-05-26 14:16:28.896 X[50414:60b] <UINavigationController: 0x23e87be0>
2014-05-26 14:16:28.896 X[50414:60b] {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
//In-Call Status Bar Deactivated
2014-05-26 14:16:29.774 X[50414:60b] <UINavigationController: 0x23e87be0>
2014-05-26 14:16:29.774 X[50414:60b] {{0, 20}, {320, 460}}
```

Comment: Interesting observation, I would say its a bug from Apple. AutoLayout would fix this for you though

Comment: @JackWu How will autolayout fix it, when the problem is occurring in the navigation controllers layout code, which is above the user's autolayout views. System views do not use autolayout for performance reasons.

Comment: Ok, you can forget my edit, I was trying to access my navigationController frame on UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification which doesn't have an updated frame at notification time, the weird part is, the statusBar frame is actually updated